# Make child containers inherit parent container height, if sibling is overflowing

Tags: html, css

I created an outer container, in which are at least two child containers. One of those 2 containers (inner container 1) has a content which make it overflow in its height. By that the outer container is growing as well.

The 2nd inner container is inheriting the height of the outer container, but it just retrieves the height of the outer container which is set to a certain value.

How do I make the second container grow to the full height of the outer container?

Hint: I kinda have the feeling that it's not possible at all.

Here a snippet:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}

.outer-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.overflowing-container {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: salmon;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.inherit-height-container {
  height: inherit;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: salmon;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.large-element {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container padding">
  <div class="overflowing-container padding">
    <div class="large-element"></div>
    <div class="large-element"></div>
    <div class="large-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inherit-height-container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually it's working as you explained but not as you may think simply because the height of an element doesn't consider the scroll or overflowed part which is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your html, you can just add an inner wrapper and make it flex:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.padding {
  padding: 10px;
}

.outer-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.overflowing-container {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: salmon;
  margin-right: 5px;       /* not sure if you want this gap */
}

.inherit-height-container {
  /* remove height from this */
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: salmon;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.large-element {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container padding">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="overflowing-container padding">
      <div class="large-element"></div>
      <div class="large-element"></div>
      <div class="large-element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inherit-height-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing! Flexbox is underrated in so many ways... Thank you for your quick help!

Comment: Yeah I pretty much use it for most things nowadays - just waiting for grid to become standard because that looks even better!